# How to clear object from previous frame in Flash with AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have an object (MovieClip) on stage at some frame, and at the next frame, even though the object is visually removed, it is still there (it has an internal function that generates something on stage periodically, and the stage objects *are* being generated). I know I can simply stop the action while leaving the frame, but the object will eat up memory and maybe even CPU time for some background actions (and this is a AIR to iOS project so I care about memory and performance). How can I get rid of the object entirely? I expect everything to be removed when I navigate to another frame if it's a designer-placed object (if the object is *not* generated by ActionScript) and this is the case, but it only gets visually removed.

Thanks,
Can.

Comment: Your internal function is probably keeping it from being garbage collected (posting that function may help find a solution).   How are you visually removing the object?  (having a new keyframe on the timeline without it,  or via code?)

Comment: Ok, here is my internal function: protected function enterFrameHandler(e:Event){
   timer++;
   if(timer == targetTime){
    timer = 0;
    generateFunction(x, y);
   }
  }
where generateFunction is a function object which is reference to a function defined in the stage. I'm removing the object via keyframe. Just if it makes sense, my object is instance named at stage, but not referenced anywhere other than that frame. the project is in general extremely complicated (function objects everywhere etc.) so it's not easy to tell anything straightforward (and it's too big to post here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just null your object reference and it's listeners.

```
...
myMovieClip.removeListeners();//class function
myMovieClip.parent.removeChild(myMovieClip);
myMovieclip = null;
...
```

Comment: Yes, you can remove every `DisplayObject`. Note that you **have to define** `removeListeners()`.

Comment: ok it worked. somehow i remembered as designed-generated objects could not be removed from the stage with actionscript. thanks anyway.